# Powershell beginner here, cant figure out how to transfer parameters from funtions to outside the function, like this

Tags: powershell

Heres an example that wont give a value to the $Prompt outside the function, atleast not from my perspective

```
function funkyfunction {
     $Prompt = Read-Host "Write something"
}

funkyfunction
Write-Host "You wrote: $Prompt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return the `Prompt` variable

```
function funkyfunction {
     $Prompt = Read-Host "Write something"
     return $Prompt
}

$Prompt = (funkyfunction)
Write-Host "You wrote: $Prompt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you are going to output all the time, is simply to use the [variable squeezing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=variable%20squeezing&form=ANNTH1&refig=de689633eefe4f97b370b5bda1ba34dd&sp=1&qs=SC&pq=variabel%20squeezin&sk=PRES1&sc=1-17&cvid=de689633eefe4f97b370b5bda1ba34dd) also, the [variable scope](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20about%20variable%20scope%20&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20about%20variable%20scope%20&sc=1-32&sk=&cvid=AE3E4DDB806042B789DA8E83F65BE5EB) is important.

```
function funkyfunction 
{
     $Script:Prompt = Read-Host "Write something"
}

funkyfunction

# Output to the screen is the default, so Write-* not really needed
"You wrote: $Prompt"

# Results
<#
Write something: test
You wrote: test
#>
```

Or squeezing

```
function funkyfunction 
{
     ("You wrote: $(($Prompt = Read-Host 'Write something'))")
}

funkyfunction

# Results
<#
Write something: test
You wrote: test
#>
```